# Acquire lots of citation data from BigQuery by application

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-patent-search

How can I realize my purpose there are ten of thousands of numbers like CN201510747352 in a Excel document.

```
SELECT 
  p.application_number AS app, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.publication_number) Citations 
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p,
UNNEST(citation) c
WHERE p.application_number **IN ('CN-201510747352-A')** 
GROUP BY p.application_number
```

I want search tens of thousands of data like CN-201510747352-A, is there any convenient ways to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import your Excel spreadsheet into Google sheets.
2. Create a federated BigQuery table pointing to your Google sheet:

[image]

3. Now you can write queries that `` SELECT * FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications ``, while filtering from your sheet with `` WHERE p.application_number IN (SELECT app_n FROM `my.sheet`) ``.

Comment: How do I open the Create Table page? Could you send me a link?

Comment: Would you mind sending me a detail solution? I'm a newbie here, so I cannot understand the answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know the third step and what should be filled in location in the second step?

Comment: Query Failed
Error: Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 1, column 10. Was expecting: <EOF>
Job ID: independent-tea-223707:US.bquijob_6840ba32_1675838bbf9
SQL

1
SELECT * FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications

Comment: Could you give me a detail instruction to realize it?

Comment: Error: Invalid table name: `Mypatent.myappnum` [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]

Comment: It didn't work out. Would you mind sending me a complementary SQL order to realize it?